# Gentoo Installation

Tags: linux, gentoo

I'm trying to install Gentoo from Gentoo livedvd on a lenovo y5070 machine
my machine doesn't have internal cdrom so I don't know how I must change following codes During installation

```
//Configuration OF FSTAB
File: nano -w /etc/fstab
/dev/sda3   /            ext4    defaults,noatime     1 1
/dev/sda1   /boot        ext2    defaults,noatime     1 2
/dev/sda2   none         swap    sw                   0 0
/dev/cdrom  /mnt/cdrom   auto    noauto,user          0 0
proc        /proc        proc    defaults             0 0
shm         /dev/shm     tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noexec  0 0
```

and

```
//Copy kernel image and initramfs from the LiveDVD to your new system
mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom/
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom/
cp /mnt/cdrom/boot/gentoo /boot/kernel
cp /mnt/cdrom/boot/gentoo.igz /boot/initramfs
```

Comment: Hi! It's not completely clear what you are asking: if you don't have a CD player, how are you booting the Live DVD, and is this part of your question? Maybe, on the contrary, you already successfully installed Gentoo and are just asking for configuration details?

Answer (score 2):

Don't skip the configuration of fstab, just remove all lines pointing to cdrom.

And copy the kernel would look like the following:

```
//Copy kernel image and initramfs from the pendrive to your new system
mkdir -p /mnt/usb
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
cp /mnt/usb/boot/gentoo /boot/kernel
cp /mnt/usb/boot/gentoo.igz /boot/initramfs
```

Change `sdb1` to your actual usb device, which you may find with

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb*
```